# Problèm with vidéo responsive

Tags: video, responsive

sorry for my english...

I try to make my vidéo responsive only with .css.width but it doesn't work.

I cannot use aspect-ratio property even if it works perfectly cause of my teacher.

I only Can work on CSS.width ans CSS.max-width, but i have no clue... Any ideas?

```
Iframe{

     width:100%
```

}

.contenair{

```
width:100%;
display:flex;
```

}

Comment: Is `contenair` a real class name you use or a typo?..

Comment: Thanks for answer, It's a real class name. I've resolved the problèm. Just i had to use a height for différent @media. 